# "is not of type LIST" error

Tags: debugging, lisp, common-lisp

I am doing Exercise 14.11 in "A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation," and wrote the following function:

```
(defmacro compile-machine (nodes)
  `(progn ,@(mapcar #'compile-node nodes)))
```

When calling `(compile-machine *nodes*)`, where `*nodes*` is a list of `NODE` structures, I get the following error:

```
Error: *NODES* is not of type LIST.
```

So I see what `*nodes*` *is*, and

```
CL-USER 116 > *nodes*
(#<Node START> #<Node HAVE-5> #<Node HAVE-10> #<Node HAVE-15> #<Node HAVE-20> #<Node HAVE-25> #<Node END>)

CL-USER 117 > (type-of *nodes*)
CONS

CL-USER 118 > (listp *nodes*)
T
```

It seems as if `*nodes*` is indeed a list. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: More code that can perhaps clarify

```
(defun compile-arc (arc)
  `((equal this-input ',(arc-label arc))
    (format t "~&~A" ,(arc-action arc))
    (,(node-name (arc-to arc)) (rest input-syms))))

(defun compile-node (node)
  `(defun ,(node-name node) (input-syms &aux (this-input (first input-syms)))
     (cond ((null input-syms) ',(node-name node))
           ,@(mapcar #'compile-arc (node-outputs node)) ;isn't this basically the same?
           (t (error "No arc from ~A with label ~A."    ;and yet Lisp doesn't complain
                     ',(node-name node) this-input)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `*NODES*` is a list, but itself it is a symbol.

Comment: @wrongusername: as always when you have a symbol. You compute the value of the symbol. See SYMBOL-VALUE or EVAL.

Comment: Ah, that worked perfectly, thanks! But how come I didn't need to use `eval` in `compile-node`? How does calling another function help prevent this error?

Comment: @wrongusername: if you call compile-node with a symbol as the argument, you have the same problem.

Comment: Oh! That is true. Come to think of it, I've never called it with a symbol before. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are not writing a *function* but a *macro*.

A macro operates on *code*.  Your code `(compile-machine *nodes*)` gets *macro-expanded* to other code, which then is executed.  The argument to your macro is the unevaluated symbol `*nodes*`.  You cannot `mapcar` a symbol.

It seems to me that you actually do want to write a function.  Use `defun` for that:

```
(defun compile-machine (nodes)
  (mapcar #'compile-node nodes))
```

Comment: Thank you! Certainly seems like it, except now I have to redefine `compile-node` as a macro :)

Comment: @wrongusername: What?  Why do you think that?  You cannot pass a macro like a function!

Comment: oh, because my `compile-node` creates a list that was supposed to be executed by `compile-machine`, but since it's a function the list returned won't be evaluated. Should I stick with using `compile-machine` as a macro then?

Comment: @wrongusername: Why doesn't `compile-node` just execute directly?

Comment: How can I make it do that? I thought it needs to be a macro if you want to build a list and then evaluate it?

Comment: @wrongusername:  You are at the wrong conceptual level.  Macros operate on code that you, the programmer, are writing.  They are nothing magical.  Backquotes are just syntactic sugar.  If you want to evaluate something, you could call `eval` on it.  This might even be the right thing to do here in the context of compilation (it is almost always a code smell in other contexts).

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, I am not really manipulating any code here. I changed them to functions calling `eval` and they work fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

*nodes* is not a list in this case, it's a symbol. The "magic" of macros is that you, the macro writer, get to evaluate the argumetns -- not the Lisp reader.

So, you're passing in *nodes*, which is a symbol. You'll need to deference it to get it's value.

Perhaps like this (caveat I'm really rusty here on this, this may well be wrong, but the basic premise is close)

```
(defmacro compile-machine (nodes)
  `(progn ,@(mapcar #'compile-node ,nodes)))
```

Comment: I see :) But using a comma before `nodes` does not seem to help. I successfully called a function like this, even using mapcar, in a previous function